# How to enter console equivalent commands in shiny for interactive functions?

Tags: r, shiny

Ok, so i'm sure I worded the question wrong, but is there any way to accomplish the equivalent of entering 1 into the console in Shiny.

Basically I want the following to work in Shiny:

```
library(quantmod)
library(fPortfolio)


# Get data

data1 <- getSymbols(c("VEU","SPY","VWO","AGG"),
                from = "2016-01-01",
                to = "2017-01-01")
data2 <- do.call(merge, lapply(data1, function(x) Ad(get(x))))
data3 <- na.omit(ROC(data2,n = 1,"discrete"))
colnames(data3) <- gsub(".Adjusted","",colnames(data3))
data4 <- as.timeSeries(data3)

# fPortfolio options

portfolioOptions<-portfolioFrontier(data4)
plot(portfolioOptions)
```

After this we get the following in the console:

```
Make a plot selection (or 0 to exit): 

1:   Plot Efficient Frontier
2:   Add Minimum Risk Portfolio
3:   Add Tangency Portfolio
4:   Add Risk/Return of Single Assets
5:   Add Equal Weights Portfolio
6:   Add Two Asset Frontiers [LongOnly Only]
7:   Add Monte Carlo Portfolios
8:   Add Sharpe Ratio [Markowitz PF Only]

Selection:
```

Is there any way to input 1-8 into the selection on Shiny and render the plot accordingly?

Comment: A series of check boxes would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `which` argument to specify which plots to plot each time:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"), 
                      textInput("num", "Enter choice", "1")),
         server=function(input, output, session){
           plotlist <- reactiveValues()
           observeEvent(input$num, {
             if(!is.null(input$num)){
               if(input$num=="1")
                 plotlist$l <- 1
               else
                 plotlist$l <- c(plotlist$l, as.numeric(input$num))
             }})
           output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(portfolioOptions, which=plotlist$l))
         })
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.